# Mongoose - how to tap schema middleware into the 'init' event?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

It is suggested in the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that I should be able to control the flow using middleware that plugs in to the "init" hook.

However, I have so far had success only with "save" and "validate".

When I do something like this, neither of these middleware ever get called:

```
MySchema.post( "init", function (next) { console.log("post init") });
MySchema.pre( "init", function (next) { console.log("pre init") });
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It turns out that the "init" event/hook is not fired when creating a new Model, it is only fired, when loading an existing model from the database. It seems that I should use the pre/validate hook instead.

Comment: is this still true? I seem to be getting my post init called after initial creation, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used middleware like `MySchema.post('init', function() { ... });` with Mongoose which is then executed for each model instance loaded in a `find` query.  Note that there isn't a `next` parameter to call with this middleware, it should just return when done.