# Adding default values to mongoose models at runtime

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to have default values for certain fields in my mongoose models. The trick is I don't want to store these values in the database, but what to add them when the model is initialized.

Please help.

Comment: I tried searching for some event which is fired after an mongoose object is initialized, but did find any such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an `'init'` [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) function for the schema which runs when a model instance is loaded from the database.  That should let you manipulate the instance  to add your defaults as needed.

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221368/mongoose-how-to-tap-schema-middleware-into-the-init) for more details as the docs are pretty spare on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a json file?
Using a require('path/to/json' ) you can acces to it and get the values.
Im actually doing something like that, but using the same JSON SCHEMA wich is build for validation purpose.